# Prefix string matching using Chosen jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-chosen

We are using the [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) jquery plugin for converting a long options list of the select element into a searchable autocomplete input field.

Is it possible to influence/configure the matching behavior of search terms? Right now Chosen seems to split all option terms into words and performs a prefix search on all words of an option term. The desired behavior we need is to have a prefix search on the option term only.
So search for "Island" should match an option like

> **Island** of ....
>
> **Island** of Hope
>
> **Island** of Disaster

but not

> Easter **Island**s

Answer (score 8):

Today I used `Chosen jQuery Plugin` and faced the same issue it was searching string in option term prefix.

Searching for the solution I found it was a registered issue at [`GitHub`](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/978).

The solution was using `search_contains` option.

And I solved the problem by using following configuration.

```
$("select").chosen({enable_split_word_search:true,search_contains:true});
```